# processing data for templates in express/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rendering, pug

I'm developing extension to an existing app using expressjs. By requirements I need to do server side rendering. Our API server is running on JAVA.

In my express app, I'm going to have to render page while making serverside calls to JAVA server. For example, I'm going to call getCategories, getVendors, getReviews etc APIs in order get data that I need to pass to rendering template.

What is a good way to accomplish this? I mean pack all of that into a single object and pass to `res.render()` method. Could you please provide me with some basic examples? I imagine that I would need to create a module that does all of this and returns some nice object...

All of the examples on the internet show something like `res.render('index', { data: 'someData'})`, however in this case data is bootstrapped. I would need a data to be compiled with several API calls and then passed to the rendering method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on whether you want to call your Java API server side or client side.

If server side, your express route containing `res.render()` will need to collect all the information it needs from Java before rendering the page. If your API is slow, the page load will be slow. If possible, use something like [async.parallel](https://npmjs.org/package/async) to avoid blocking.

Your code sample is correct. `res.render('index', { foo: 'bar'})`
This would add the `foo` variable to the root scope of your view. How you build up the data structure is entirely up to you. I would recommend using async.parallel and/or async.series to collate all of the data. If they are all completely independent, run them in parallel.

```
// an example of how to run each in parallel and then render the view.
var getCategories = function(done) {
    // get something
    done();
};
var data = {};
async.parallel([
    getCategories, // <-- adds to the data structure
    getVendors,
    getReviews
], function(err) {
    res.render('index', { data: data });
});
```

Your other option is using express to render the base page and using something like jQuery to hit the Java API and update the relevant page fragments.